# Adding dipole moments in chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry

I haven't been able to find anything in chemfig for adding dipole moments to my molecules beyond creating custom arrows with tikz, which is more involved than I'd like at the moment. Is there some standard way to do this?

Comment: [Potentially of interest.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162175/73570) This doesn't help with the arrow situation to actually show the dipole however.

Comment: Can you add an image what you want obtain?

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment than an answer but I use the `tikz` `arrow` `|->` to overcome my issue. It's not exactly what I want but gets me out of a bind for the moment.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
        \chemabove[3pt]{C}{\scriptstyle\delta -}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{a})-
        \chemabove[3pt]{H}{\scriptstyle\delta +}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{b})
        }
\chemmove{
          \draw[|->, very thick] (b)--(a);
         } 
\qquad
\chemfig{
         \chemabove[3pt]{O}{\scriptstyle\delta -}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{c})-
         \chemabove[3pt]{H}{\scriptstyle\delta +}(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{d})
        }
\chemmove{
          \draw[|->, very thick] (d)--(c);
          }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Additionally, you can set padding for the vertical line at the beginning of the arrow with underscores (3 or 4), and also use `chemfig`'s CF arrow head type: `\draw[____|-CF, thick] (b)--(a);` to mke it look more consistent and according to the common notation ([result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45s6m.png)).

Answer (score 2):

Create a command called name bond as such :

```
\newcommand\namebond[4][5pt]{\chemmove{\path(#2)--(#3)node[midway,sloped,yshift=#1]{#4};}}
```

Then you can just use textcomp to implement a normal rightarrow.

```
\usepackage{textcomp}

\chemfig{@{a}H-[1]@{b}\chemabove{N}{\uparrow}(<[6]@{c}H)-[7]@{d}H} 

\namebond{a}{b}{\textrightarrow}
\namebond{c}{b}{\textrightarrow}
\namebond{d}{b}{\textleftarrow}
```

[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
\scalebox{1.25}{
\chemfig{C(-[:90]H(-[::270,0.5,,,draw=none]@{e}))
(-[:-150]H(-[::270,0.25,,,draw=none]@{c}))
(-[:-100]H(-[::90,0.60,,,draw=none]@{g}))
(-[:-30]H(-[::52,0.75,,,draw=none]@{a}))
(-[::-30,0.5,,,draw=none]@{h})
(-[::30,0.6,,,draw=none]@{f})
(-[::105,0.25,,,draw=none]@{d})
(-[::15,0.75,,,draw=none]@{b})
(-[::0,2.5,,,draw=none]@{j})}}
\chemmove{
      \draw[|->, very thick] (a)--(b);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (c)--(d);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (e)--(f);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (g)--(h);
      \node at (j) {$\mu = 0$};
     }
\qquad
\scalebox{1.25}{
\chemfig{@{x1}\lewis{2:,N}
(-[:-150]H(-[::270,0.25,,,draw=none]@{c}))
(-[:-100]H(-[::90,0.60,,,draw=none]@{g}))
(-[:-30]H(-[::52,0.75,,,draw=none]@{a})
(-[::0,1.25,,,draw=none]@{e}))
(-[::-30,0.5,,,draw=none]@{h})
(-[::105,0.25,,,draw=none]@{d})
(-[::15,0.75,,,draw=none]@{b})
(-[::0,2,,,draw=none]@{f})}}
\chemmove{
      \draw[|->, very thick] (a)--(b);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (c)--(d);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (g)--(h);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (e)--++(90:1.25) node [midway, right] {$\mu > 0$};
     }
\qquad
\scalebox{1.25}{
\chemfig{O(-[:210]H(-[::270,0.25,,,draw=none]@{c}))
(-[:-30]H(-[::52,0.75,,,draw=none]@{a})
(-[::0,1.25,,,draw=none]@{e}))
(-[::30,0.75,,,draw=none]@{b})
(-[::105,0.25,,,draw=none]@{d})
(-[::0,2,,,draw=none]@{f})}}
\chemmove{
      \draw[|->, very thick] (a)--(b);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (c)--(d);
      \draw[|->, very thick] (e)--++(90:1.25) node [midway, right] {$\mu > 0$};
     }
```

[image]