# Colored charges in chemfig?

Tags: color, latex3, chemfig

I created a lewis formula with chemfig:

[image]

Now I want to color only the charges like OP did in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162175/draw-molecule-charge-in-latex-using-chemfig).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\sffamily{#1}}
\newcommand*\forcelen[1]{#1/\CF@atom@sep}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{\charge{90=\|,90:7pt=$\delta^-$}{N}(-[0]\charge{0:6pt=$\delta^+$}{H})(-[4]\charge{180:6pt=$\delta^+$}{H})(-[6]\charge{270:6pt=$\delta^+$}{H})}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use what I thought was his code but it didn't work:

```
\newcommand{\pol}[1]{\rlap{${}^{^{\color{red} \delta #1}}$}}
```

I also found this in the documentation:

```
\setchemfig{atom style=red}
```

Is there a chemfig style like "charge style" or something like that? Where can I find a list of all available chemfig styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the expected output:

[image]

I modified the `\pol` command to yield an output similar to the code in your question. By default the output of `\pol` is red, but you can use its optional argument (such as `\pol[blue]{+}`) to locally override the color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\sffamily{#1}}
\newcommand*\forcelen[1]{#1/\CF@atom@sep}

\newcommand{\pol}[2][red]{$\color{#1} \delta^{#2}$}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{\charge{90=\|,90:7pt=\pol{-}}{N}(-[0]\charge{0:6pt=\pol{+}}{H})(-[4]\charge{180:6pt=\pol{+}}{H})(-[6]\charge{270:6pt=\pol[blue]{+}}{H})}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. Now I can color the negative charge blue and the positive charges red.